# how to solve this type of error in salesforce trigger test class

Tags: unit-test

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   NWSHOP.CourseSessionTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object
>
> Class.NWSHOP.trgr_BookingsTriggerHandler.updateCourseSessionED: line
>   903, column 1 Trigger.NWSHOP.CourseSessionTrigger: line 56, column 1:
>   []

---

```
Set<Id> setCustId = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> setServiceId = new Set<Id>();

for(NWSHOP__Bookings__c booking: Trigger.new) {
    NWSHOP__Bookings__c oldBooking = Trigger.oldmap.get(booking.id);
    if(booking.NWSHOP__Service_Record__c <> oldBooking.NWSHOP__Service_Record__c 
        && oldBooking.NWSHOP__Service_Record__c <> null 
        && booking.NWSHOP__Service_Record__c <> null) {
        //reset the service back to original value
        //booking.NWSHOP__Service_Record__c = oldBooking.NWSHOP__Service_Record__c;
        setCustId.add(booking.nwshop__contact_name__c);
        setServiceId.add(booking.NWSHOP__Service_Record__c);
    }
}

// delete extra record created by dispatch process.
if(setServiceId.size() > 0) {
    /**
     * check if there was record related to Home Buyer development outside of the current records
     */
    List<NWSHOP__Application__c> lstHBE = [Select id from NWSHOP__Application__c
        where NWSHOP__Customer_Name__c in :setCustId
        and id in :setServiceId
        and name like '%Home Buyer Development%'];

    if(lstHBE.size() >0) {
        List<NWSHOP__Application__c> lstExtraHBE = [Select id from NWSHOP__Application__c
            where NWSHOP__Customer_Name__c in :setCustId
            and id not in :setServiceId
            and name like '%Home Buyer Development%'];
        if(lstExtraHBE.size() > 0 ) {
            delete [Select id from NWSHOP__ActionPlan__c where NWSHOP__Application__c=:lstExtraHBE ];
            delete lstExtraHBE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you keep deleting all this content? Either delete the whole post or leave it in an answerable state...